# What is the correct JBoss module dependency to reference org.jboss.resteasy in a static module?

Tags: resteasy, jboss6.x, jboss-modules

I am attempting to deploy a static module that uses resteasy, which comes pre-installed as a system module:

```
[me@localhost:3 modules]$ ls -l system/layers/base/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/main/
total 660K
-rw-r--r-- 1 coer2 admin 7.7K Jun  2  2017 async-http-servlet-3.0-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 coer2 admin 2.1K Mar 27  2015 module.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 coer2 admin 646K Jun  2  2017 resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar
```

however my attempts to reference it are failing.  My module looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="."/>
    <resource-root path="JWTAUTHENTICATOR-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="org.jboss.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
    <module name="javax.security.jacc.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.picketbox"/>
    <module name="org.picketlink.federation"/>
    <module name="org.picketlink.federation.bindings"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
    <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.stream.api"/>
    <module name="org.infinispan"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.web"/>
    <module name="org.slf4j"/>
</dependencies>
```

The following produces log output that looks like:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
>   11:47:53,135 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.valve.JWTAUTHENTICATOR: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.valve.JWTAUTHENTICATOR: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy-jaxrs:main
>   Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy-jaxrs:main

Table 3.1 in the module [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#javax.ws.rs.core.Application), indicates this config should be sufficient, but previous experience with static module dependencies leaves me not surprised that it doesn't.

I suspect that it's less about this specific module and maybe a missing dependency that resteasy needs. Unfortunately, jboss module docs are not forthcoming with this information.  Would appreciate insight.

Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that the package namespace maps to the directory structure, so the specific module to be added needs to be appended to the package namespace:

```
<module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
```